# Filter elements that are in an array

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using React Native. I have a list of food categories:

```
  const categoryData = [
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Burger",
  icon: icons.burger,
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "Salat",
  icon: icons.salad,
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: "Drinks",
  icon: icons.drinks,
}];
```

and a selected restaurant:

```
  const selectedRestaurant = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Tom's Burger",
  rating: 4.8,
  categories: [1, 3],
};
```

I want to have an array *offeredCategories* that only contains the categories that are offered by the restaurant. In this case only the category burger and drinks should be displayed.

I have tried to filter the categoryData and used the following, but it said *includes* is not a function. Are there any other options?

```
const offeredCategories = categoryData.filter((item) => item.id.includes(selectedRestaurant.categories))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***Array*** *includes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) a specific value, therefore your `selectedRestaurant.categories`, not your `item.id`

```js
const icons = {};
const categoryData = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Burger",
    icon: icons.burger,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Salat",
    icon: icons.salad,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Drinks",
    icon: icons.drinks,
  }
];

const selectedRestaurant = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Tom's Burger",
  rating: 4.8,
  categories: [1, 3],
};

const offeredCategories = categoryData.filter((item) =>  
  selectedRestaurant.categories.includes(item.id)
);

console.log(offeredCategories);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

> The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain
> value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

In your code, you're trying to use the `includes` method on an integer and not an array.

**Edit:**

This should allow you to filter out the categories.

```js
const offeredCategories = categoryData.filter((item) => selectedRestaurant.categories.includes(item.id))
```

The only issue was that you were checking an item to see if it contained an array where-as the includes statement is checking an array to see if it contained an item.